# How do I prevent code injection when executing something using system?

Tags: bash, scheme, racket, code-injection

I'm writing a script that checks something about a Docker container; which container it is depends on user input. So I have code like this:

```
(define pipes (process (string-append "docker inspect " name)))
```

To get the result of calling `docker inspect $name` in the shell. How can I protect this from code injection? Someone could enter `someName ; sudo rm -rf / --no-preserve-root` and the result wouldn't be nice. I could make it so that it has the effect of `docker inspect "$name"` or even put it between single quotes but in both cases, someone could enter `someName"` or `someName'` instead and the problem is back.

Comment: I think you want to use [`process*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fsystem..rkt%29._process%2A%29%29), which takes as separate arguments the name of the command and its arguments. Something like `(process* "docker" "inspect" name)`?

Comment: @chepner It's getting a bit late here so I won't test it until tomorrow, but if this indeed fixes the issues (which I expect it will, it would be weird if it were just syntactic sugar) then this would the accepted answer

Comment: Cool, I didn't have any convenient way to test it myself (the rename from PLT Scheme to Racket was still years in the future the last time I wrote any Scheme).

Comment: From my tests it seems to be safe, please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `process*` function, which takes separate arguments for the command name and its arguments, bypassing the shell to run the program.

```
(process* "docker" "inspect" name)
```